# OpenGL Lighitng

Tags: opengl, graphics, glut, light

I am new to OpenGL, I made this to switch menu in between ambient, diffuse and specular, position light. It works but looks weird [image: This is the ambient]
[image: This is diffuse]

The code (relevant part ) is:

```
void gfxinit(void)
{
    GLfloat light_ambient[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat light_diffuse[] = { 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat light_direction[] = { -1, -2, -1, 1 };
    GLfloat light_specular[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat light_position[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
    GLfloat global_ambient[] = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0 };
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); //background Color

    list = glGenLists(1);
    glNewList(list, GL_COMPILE);
    glutSolidSphere(1.0, 30, 12);
    glEndList();

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, global_ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT2, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT3, GL_POSITION, light_position);
    glLightf(GL_LIGHT4, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 2.0);
}
```

and

```
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, tdist);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)spinx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)spiny, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef((GLfloat)spinz, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, gray);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, cyan);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, gray);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_POSITION, white);
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 70);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, light_param);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);

    if (value == 2) {//ambient
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
        glPolygonOffset(polyfactor, polyunits);
        glCallList(list);
        glDisable(GL_LIGHT0);
    }
    else if (value == 3) {//diffuse
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
        glPolygonOffset(polyfactor, polyunits);
        glCallList(list);
        glDisable(GL_LIGHT1);
    }
```

Really thanks if someone can tell me whether there is mistake here or not! Thanks!

Comment: What is the question? Note, you use the deprecated [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) light model.

Comment: @Rabbid76 My question is whether the screen are showing right or not

Comment: It seems to be correct.

Comment: I am not sure whether the ambient and diffuse are like that. When I searched and learnt from online material, the ambient should not be this but my screen shows this. So I would like to confirm whether it is correct or not.

Comment: Online shows the ambient should not be realistic. so I raised this question. Thanks for answering!!

Comment: The ambient light is constant, independent on the direction or normal vector of the surface.

Comment: @Rabbid76 thanks! may I also ask about position light? what is it exactly.... thanks

Comment: A directional light has just a direction, each object is illuminated at the _same_ side, independent on its position. It is used for a light source that is far away, for instance for the sun. A point light has a position. The light is emitted from a point in the world, thus the direction of the light depends on the position of the object relative to the position of the light source. For instance it is used for a bulb.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks so much for the answer! So the reason why my position light is not functioning is that the light did not point to the object!